# Changing only the directory in an image source using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select menu with four color options, and three images for each option. I want to make the image directory change for all three images when the user selects a different option in the select menu.

```
<img src="images/black/img1.jpg" />
<img src="images/black/img2.jpg" />
<img src="images/black/img3.jpg" />

<select>
    <option value="black">Black</option> 
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
    <option value="teal">Teal</option>
</select>
```

I'm assuming there is a way to use wildcards in Jquery, but apparently I'm not proficient enough to figure it out.

Comment: Can you post the jQuery you tried please.

Comment: if you want jquery, start by using .split().  Then make some statement to replace the color section.  Show us some script and we can help you more

Comment: I haven't tried anything up to now, I'm just not proficient enough. If I can do it with JS, that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - note I gave imgs a class and the select an ID

```js
$(function() { // when page has loaded
  $("#color").on("change",function() { // assign the event handler
    var col=$(this).val(); // value of select
    $(".img").each(function() { // I gave the imgs a class to do this
      var srcParts = this.src.split("/"); // split the src on /
      this.src="images/"+col+"/"+srcParts.pop(); // take the image name 
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img" src="images/black/img1.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="images/black/img2.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="images/black/img3.jpg" />

<select id="color">
    <option value="black">Black</option> 
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
    <option value="teal">Teal</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This replaces the directory as needed, but inserts the domain name instead of "img1.jpg" etc. after the directory.

Comment: Not anymore it doesn't. The pop fixed it. I should have used the attr but changed my mind. PS I am off to bed now.

Comment: Brilliant! My sincerest thanks!